# Pass table-valued parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper, table-valued-parameters

In my project we are using Dapper to connect with database for operations.

I have created a stored procedure in my SQL Server database as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Check
    @TestTableType [dbo].[TestTableType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT 
      TestTableType.BrokerNPN,
      CASE WHEN Sales.BrokerNPN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as isBrokerNPNExist
  FROM 
      [dbo].[tbl_Sales] Sales
  LEFT JOIN 
      @TestTableType TestTableType ON Sales.BrokerNPN = TestTableType.BrokerNPN
END
```

And in C# I am trying to consume my stored procedure with a TVP like this:

```
public void CheckSP(List<string> ParamData)
{
    using (var connection = new ConnectionProvider("DbName").GetOpenConnection())
    {
        var dt = new DataTable("dbo.TestTableType");
        dt.Columns.Add("NPN", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("12345");

        // First attempt
        var result = connection.Query<CheckData>("usp_Check", new { BrokerNPN = ParamData }, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

        // Second attempt
        var result = connection.Query<CheckData>("usp_Check", new { BrokerNPN = dt}, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    }
}
```

But I am not able to pass the TVP to the stored procedure.

For the first attempt, I am getting this error

> Procedure or function CheckBrokerNPNExist has too many arguments specified

And for the second attempt, I cannot use pass `DataTable` directly.

Comment: What error encountered when executing? Your code looks eligible, it should executing stored procedure query.

Comment: You create `DataTable`, but not using it

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have added other way i tried to use TVP using DataTable.

Comment: I don't see `CheckBrokerNPNExist` procedure/function on your code. Can you add it for reference? The problem comes from additional arguments in `CheckBrokerNPNExist` which longer than declared one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same column name  in [dbo].[TestTableType] in c# code

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just using a **wrong** name for the parameter...

See your stored procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Check
    @TestTableType [dbo].[TestTableType] READONLY
```

Your parameter is called `@TestTableType` - yet when you **call** this stored procedure from C#, you're using a different name:

```
var result = connection
                .Query<CheckData>("usp_Check", 
                                  new { BrokerNPN = ParamData }, 
                                  CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

I would try to use the **same name**:

```
var result = connection
                .Query<CheckData>("usp_Check", 
                                  new { TestTableType = ParamData }, 
                                  CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```